# Randomly select an array until a specific parameter is hit

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to put together an interactive meal tracker / planner in Google Sheets.

- What I have is a table with food and info about kcal and their macro nutrition values.
- I have already put together a logic for how much kcal does somebody requires and this gives a kcal and macro nutrition for each meal per day, e.g.

  Breakfast: 518 kcal, carbohydrates 207, protein 62, fat 19

Now I want to randomly put together foods/meals from the table mentioned above until those numbers are hit automatically.

There a ways to randomly select things from an array, but I'm stuck how to combine this with a loop and a deadline.

Any idea?

Many thanks

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow. Can you clarify a little what it is you are stuck on? Is it building the array of foods/meals and how to stop the loop once you reach the kcal mark?

Comment: Please show any current code and expected input to your function (array, table structure, etc.)

Comment: We answer scripting questions not design questions.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see any update so I will just go with my assumption on what you are stuck on and say that it's building the array and making sure you stop once you reach the kCal limit.

Basically you will be working with 3 variables, `foodTable` as your food array, `mealTable` which is the meal table you will generate and some kind of kCal tracker, let's just call it `kCal`.

In essence you want to use a `do .. while` [loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/do...while) and your `while` statement is basically `kCal < target` where `target` is the value you want to reach. If you want to use each value from the `foodTable` only once then you will need to use `selectedFood = foodTable.splice(idx,1)`, if you want to be able to re-use the sime item then use `slice()` instead.

Your `idx` is a randomly generated number between 0 and `mealTable.length` (in case you are using `splice` to remove an item from the possible foods list this will ensure you do not generate an invalid number)

Then add the kCal value to your tracker with `kCal += selectedFood[0][col]` where `col` is the column number where you store the kCal value. Make sure that every time before you start the `while` loop you have `kCal = 0` to reset, if you repeat this. And keep in mind that this method does not care how much over the target kCal you will go and you might want to add some kind of `if` statement to make sure you do not run out of items before you reach your target.